# Rails not using modified gem instead of original

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

this is what I believe a simple problem I need help with. I'm trying to modify a gem's method so that I can add another argument to it. For this, I've cloned the gem's repo to a local directory and changed the code I needed. Inside my app's Gemfile I'm doing this:

`gem 'recommendable', path: "/home/aristizabal95/forked_gems/recommendable"`

And running `bundle install` afterwards. Even though the bundler says it's using my code, when I run the tests I get this error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 1..3)
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/recommendable-2.2.0/lib/recommendable/rater/recommender.rb:21:in `recommended_for'
```

which indicates that the app is not running my version of the gem, but the original one. I have no idea why it's not working, and was unable to find any issue related to this.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
This is what the Gemfile.lock looks like

```
PATH
  remote: /home/aristizabal95/forked_gems/recommendable
  specs:
    recommendable (2.2.1)
    activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    hooks (>= 0.2.1)
    redis (>= 2.2.0)
GEM
  recommendable!
```

Comment: what does the gemfile.lock look like?

Comment: Are you using `spring`? If so, you might want to try `spring stop` in the console.

Comment: @BradWerth gonna add it to the question for clarity

Comment: @jvillian Now I can't start rails console :(

Comment: Well, that's probably good new/bad news. It probably means you're now using your local gem (good news). It probably also means you need to do some mods to make the gem work locally (bad news). Can you add to your question the error stack trace?

Comment: @jvillian I had to increase the number of inotify watchers to get the console working again, and I'm no longer getting the `ArgumentError`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `spring` still has the gem from the original gem source loaded.

To force `spring` to reload the gem (from your local source), do:

```
spring stop
```

in the console. Then restart your server and you should be using the gem from your local source.